# Adding a link to an image

Tags: 8, navigation, media

Is there a module or a way in core to have an Image field be a clickable link to a URL that is either entered as an additional setting for the Image field or can be pulled from another field that stores that URL.

This https://www.drupal.org/project/linked_field looks like what I want, but there doesn't seem to be a token that I can use that will do what I want.

This also looks exactly like I want but it's for D7. https://www.drupal.org/project/linkimagefield

I'm using this for a Custom Field Type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now (perhaps it was not the case back in the days...)
https://www.drupal.org/project/linked_field allows you to link your image directly to the content links fields without using tokens

Answer (score 2):

If you are already building a custom field type, you could add properties for the link to your field:

```
class MyLinkField extends FieldItemBase {

  public static function propertyDefinitions(StorageDefinition $storage) {
    ...  
    $properties['title'] = DataDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('Title'));
    $properties['url'] = DataDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('URL'));
  }
```

and use it in the field formatter:

```
class MyLinkFieldFormatter extends FormatterBase {

  public function viewElements(FieldItemListInterface $items, $langcode) {
    $elements = [];
    foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
      $elements[$delta] = [
        '#type' => 'link', 
        '#title' => $item->title,
        '#url' => Url::fromUri($item->url),
      ];
    }
  return $elements;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a template file for your content type.

**node--[type-name].html.twig**

`<a href="{{ content.field_url }}"> {{ content.field_image }} </a>`

Comment: no, that's not the best way of providing link because you will link all wrapping containers that comes with image field including contextual links